# Make a button activate JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

What I would like to accomplish today is making a button activate JavaScript code. For example, lets take a code to make snow appear on the page. At first, the page doesn't have snow falling, but the code is in the page. Then the visitor clicks on the button and snow starts falling on the page. That's what I want it to do.

Website to use on: http://gravitate.webs.com

Snow Code:

BEGINNING

```
<!-- -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.websimages.com/static/global/js/webs/usersites/escort.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(typeof(urchinTracker)=='function') {
    _uacct="UA-230305-2";
    _udn="none"; 
    _uff=false;
    urchinTracker();
  }
</script>

</body>

<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.ig33kstas.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-christmas/wp-christmas.js.php?swf=http://www.ig33kstas.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-christmas/wp-christmas-EN.swf"></script>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  sitePath = "http://www.ig33kstas.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-christmas/";
  sflakesMax = 89;
  sflakesMaxActive = 64;
  svMaxX = 4;
  svMaxY = 5;
  ssnowStick = 1;
  sfollowMouse = 1;
</script>
}
</script>
```

END

What I tried that totally failed:

```
<body>
<button onclick="mysnowcode">Snow</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You seem to be confused. What you're talking about is JavaScript. HTML is merely markup.

Comment: ok, so i've tried a really dumb thing by using onclick then pastin the html code in that. Also, its okk to use JavaScript. Thanks!

Comment: The code you've shown just creates half a dozen global variables. Do you not have more code? Also, you should show the html for the button you are talking about. (Also, is that urchinTracker stuff relevant to your question? If not, delete it.)

Comment: @nnnnnn that is the code for the snow falling, not the button. thanks!
p.s. i posted the html code for the failing button

Comment: What I'm saying is that the JavaScript code you've posted won't make any snow fall because all it does is set some global variables, it doesn't do anything that would change the display of your page. Once you have the rest of the code needed to do the snow effect then your html button needs to call a JS function to start the snow as shown in Seramme's answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function makeitsnow() { ...your snowfall code... }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="makeitsnow();">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it didn't work. I will post my code soon.

Comment: Your code won't work without modifying www.ig33kstas.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-christmas/wp-christmas.js.php file. Namely, you would need to remove the call to DispMagicEmot(144,350,500); that happens at its end and call it in onclick instead (onclick="DispMagicEmot(144,350,500);"). You probably also need a <div id="MagicFace"></div> somewhere.